# Assistance with unordered lists

Tags: css

Testing out an idea at http://www.devsite11.co.uk/about-us/areas-we-cover.html i have created a background box, with three lists, the lists when displayed on a P.C are all side by side, this is as expected.
Problem i am having is when it comes to iPad or Iphone, the lists are not scaling down and are getting jumbled up.

I have played around with the %ages all to no avail.

What i would like to happen is, either the lists drop below each other, or the text reduces and stays side by side.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You need to post an example of your full code so that people can identify what's wrong.

Comment: I did try, but was not sure how to. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    .featurebox, .featurecenter, .featureright {
        min-width:250px; /* or something smaller*/
    }
```

let me know if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a min-width on each of those feature boxes, say `min-width:200px` or whatever value to keep them from collapsing too far.  Also, a class that you can apply to the common stylings on each of those boxes is the preferred way to go.

Also, you have the "left" box on the left, the "center" box on the right, and the "right" box in the center.  Try changing the float on all three of those to `float:left` to get that correct.

Answer (score 0):

At line 147 and elsewhere of your styles you have a width set of `31%`. E.g.

```
#featurebox .featureleft {
width: 31%;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-right: 10px;
float: left;
}
```

This doesn't work at small widths, so in your @media rules, make sure to change that width at an appropriate point. E.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    #featurebox .featureleft,
    #featurebox .featurecenter,
    #featurebox .featureright {width: 100%;}
}
```